# Kendo UI Grid: Custom NEWPAGe Edit Button for Ajax Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, custom-controls, telerik-grid

Is there any way to edit items in the new page from a Kendo UI AJAx Grid i dont want in-line or popup edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create template column with a link inside which points to your custom editing page. How to create links in a column is covered [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-use-action-links?).